# Pointer to pointer argument variable and how they work? e.g. function(int **ptr)

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am writing code to learn what happens when pointers are passed as arguments in a function.

```
void ptrTest(int **arg_ptr); 

int main() {
    int some_var = 5;
    int *ptr1;
    ptr1 = &some_var;

    printf("Address of some_var: %u\n\n", &some_var);
    printf("Value stored in *ptr1 (references to some_var): %u\n", ptr1);
    printf("Address of *ptr1 variable: %u\n\n", &ptr1);
    ptrTest(ptr1);
}

void ptrTest(int **arg_ptr){
    printf("Value stored in **arg_ptr (references to some_var): %u\n",arg_ptr);    
}
```

The result is as follows:

```
Address of some_var: 3119323004

Value stored in *ptr1 (references to some_var): 3119323004
Address of *ptr1 variable: 3119322992

Value stored in **arg_ptr (references to some_var): 3119323004
```

I am surprised that arg_ptr takes the value that references to address of some_var. I was expecting **arg_ptr to point to *ptr and store the value of 3119322992(referencing to the address of *ptr).

When I test pointer to pointer outside of a function, it does behave in this exact manner. Why it differs for pointer to pointer as an argument baffles me.

Can you explain to me what's happening here?

Comment: I'm surprised that compiler didn't complain that argument (`int *`) is not matching with type (`int **`)

Comment: What @SaileshD says :) A conforming compiler must give you a diagnostic message here. Voting to close this as simple typo.

Comment: Your output is not true. You never print `"Value stored in"` in your code. Please copy&paste your code and output. Do not provide random code rewritten from memory.

Comment: Real code but change the string printf for clarity and forgot to change the code. It's updated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all what is a pointer? A pointer in C/C++ is just like any other variable with a type like int, char etc. But speciality of this variable is that unlike other variable it just hold the address of a memory location. Again that memory location also might be a pointer variable or any other regular variable( int or char).

Now what is pointer of pointer? A  variable who can store the address of a pointer variable and that pointer variable might holding the address of another variable like:-

```
 int i = 10; //`i` is assign with a value  10 and `i` has its own address which we can get by `&i`;

 int *ptr1 = &i;// now ptr1 is pointer to `i` means ptr1 is assign with the
 //address of `i` hence if we dereference the address of *ptr1 we will get the value stored at that memory location
```

Now in your case

```
 void ptrTest(int **arg_ptr){
    printf("Address store in of **arg_ptr: %u\n",arg_ptr);    
}
```

So here it will work like below

```
int **arg_ptr = ptr1;//Wrong, `ptr1` is assign to `arg_ptr`, which is wrong because `arg_ptr` is a pointer to pointer type
```

So here you should store the address of a pointer but you are storing the address of a variable int which is `i`.
    Because address of `i` has been assign in statement int *ptr1 = &i; to ptr1.
    The correct assignment would be

```
arg_ptr = &ptr1; //address of a pointer not address of a int variable.
```

Now first dereferencing:-

```
  *arg_ptr; //value of a pointer ptr1 that means address of `i`

 *(*arg_ptr); or **arg_ptr;// we further dereferenced the address of ptr1 here, which is value 10
```

Now you should call your function like below:-

```
ptrTest(&ptr1);// address of a pointer.
```

Answer (score 1):

`ptrTest` expects an argument of type `int **` but you are passing `int*`. Your compiler should complain. You need to pass the address of `ptr` to the function.

```
ptrTest(&ptr1);
```

Apart from that you should use `%p` specification to print address.

```
printf("Address of some_var: %p\n\n", (void*)&some_var);
```

Answer (score 1):

When I compile your code I get a long list of errors:

```
"test.c", line 11: warning #2181-D: argument is incompatible with
          corresponding format string conversion
      printf("Address of some_var: %u\n\n", &some_var);
                                            ^

"test.c", line 12: warning #2181-D: argument is incompatible with
          corresponding format string conversion
      printf("Value stored in *ptr1 (references to some_var): %u\n", ptr1);
                                                                     ^

"test.c", line 13: warning #2181-D: argument is incompatible with
          corresponding format string conversion
      printf("Address of *ptr1 variable: %u\n\n", &ptr1);
                                                  ^

"test.c", line 14: warning #2167-D: argument of type "int *" is incompatible
          with parameter of type "int **"
      ptrTest(ptr1);
              ^

"test.c", line 18: warning #2181-D: argument is incompatible with
          corresponding format string conversion
      printf("Value stored in **arg_ptr (references to some_var): %u\n",arg_ptr);
```

Let's rewrite this code so it compiles without errors and is perhaps a little clearer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ptrTest(int **arg_ptr)
  {
  printf("Value stored in arg_ptr (points to ptr1): %#p\n", arg_ptr);
  printf("Value pointed to by arg_ptr (i.e. *arg_ptr - should be same as ptr1): %#p\n", *arg_ptr);
  printf("Value pointed to by *arg_ptr (i.e. **arg_ptr - should be same as some_var): %d\n", **arg_ptr);
  }

int main()
  {
  int some_var = 5;
  int *ptr1;

  ptr1 = &some_var;

  printf("some_var: %d\n", some_var);
  printf("Address of some_var: %#p\n\n", &some_var);
  printf("Value stored in ptr1 (should be address of some_var): %#p\n", ptr1);
  printf("Address of ptr1 variable: %#p\n\n", &ptr1);
  ptrTest(&ptr1);
  }
```

What got changed:

1. Used signed int format in printf (`%d`) instead of unsigned format
   (`%u`).
2. Used pointer format in printf (`%p`) when printing pointers.
3. Added code to `ptrTest` to follow `arg_ptr` all the way back to the
   base target of the pointer chain.
4. Added code to print the value of `some_var`
5. Changed the wording of the output to clarify what's being shown, and which values should match up.

The new version compiles without errors (HP-UX default C compiler).

When the new version is run the following output is printed:

```
some_var: 5
Address of some_var: 0x7fffecd0

Value stored in ptr1 (should be address of some_var): 0x7fffecd0
Address of ptr1 variable: 0x7fffecd4

Value stored in arg_ptr (points to ptr1): 0x7fffecd4
Value pointed to by arg_ptr (i.e. *arg_ptr - should be same as ptr1): 0x7fffecd0
Value pointed to by *arg_ptr (i.e. **arg_ptr - should be same as some_var): 5
```

Now you can follow the chain of pointers forward and back to see which pointer points to which value, and how they all link up.

Best of luck.

Comment: Much better! Followed what you wrote and it compiled without errors and warnings. Cheers.